# No "My Work" in visual studio 2012 team explorer

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Premium, and in my team explorer, all I see is Work Items, there's no My Work where I can suspend and resume tasks.

Under Home, all I see are:
Changes
Work Items
Builds
Web Access
Settings

I'm connected to team foundation service (the cloud edition, not server), with Git as my source control.

I'm looking through this exercise here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh474795.aspx

I understand that My Work is available only on premium & ultimate, so I should be able to access it, right?

How do I get My Work to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that at this point, My Work/Suspend Work isn't supported when using TFS with Git.